# Group Policy or reg hack to hide startup dialogs in XP

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, windows-registry, hacking

I have a system that I'd like to try and hide some dialogs on at startup.  I've gotten rid of login, and welcome screen and all kinds of stuff, but there are still a couple of pesky dialogs I can't seem to hide.  There is the "Loading your personal settings" dialog "Applying your personal settings" dialog.

Does anyone know how to hide them?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Have you checked your verbose messages configuration?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325376)

Comment: That article describes how to turn ON verbose messages, which are turned off by default. That's the reverse of what was asked.

Comment: Correct, an article on how to activate something can be helpful to check the current status of such a setting if one was not aware of it.  I can think of plenty of senerios where an admin might not know all of the active policy configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the (probably) gina.dll and change the graphics inside to be clear but you are probably asking for trouble at that point.

You generally want those dialogs.  Are you working with some xp embedded platform and are trying to do something stealthy?

Comment: It is for an embedded system, but running full XP...not trying to do anything stealthy, just wanted the startup to look as clean as possible.  Client wouldn't accept my solution (which was to use a different OS entirely).

Comment: Then you could probably lock down the theme, keeping the background colors the same.  Then change the graphic (it should be in the gina) to match the background color.  When you hack the gina you run the risk that a security patch in the future may overwrite your gina - but since a lot of vendors hack the gina these days (fingerprint logon, etc.) the rest of the vendors don't seem too concerned about it.  Not exactly sure on the order, but writing your own shell may deal with that as well.

Comment: they discuss that here, but you can run your program directly, or write your own windows program to only have the menus you require and lock them out of the rest of the OS.  http://www.knowledgesutra.com/forums/topic/20367-how-to-change-the-windows-xp-shell/  Pretty sure the local policies dialog you are seeing would still come up - almost 100% percent sure that's in the gina dll.

Comment: Wow.  If you wanna be hardcore you can write (or outsource) one.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx